# Does it ever make sense to read from and/or write to a bound, listening socket?

Tags: sockets, client-server, io

I'm experimenting a little with creating a socket server, in PHP. In doing so I'm trying to abstract away the kinds of sockets I think I'll be needing, that I've tentitively named:

- `ListenSocket` — the 'master' socket, that is bound to an address/port and listens for and accepts incoming connections.
- `CommunicationSocket` — a 'child' socket, that represents an accepted, incoming connection, which the server will communicate with.

As the name already kind of implies, I will only define `read()` and `write()` type of methods on the `CommunicationSocket`.

However, doing so got me wondering: does it ever make sense to read from or write to the first type of socket (the bound, listening type)?

Comment: Java uses a model like this, and it seems to work OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I interpret your question in a way that you refer to TCP/IP sockets. With UDP/IP sockets it is different.

Two scenarios:

Scenario 1: 1. bind 2. connect 3. listen
Result: You cannot listen at a connected socket.

```
>>> import socket
>>> s = socket.socket()
>>> s.bind(('', 0))
>>> s.send(b'a')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#130>", line 1, in <module>
    s.send(b'a')
OSError: [WinError 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
>>> s.connect(('google.de', 80))
>>> s.listen(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#132>", line 1, in <module>
    s.listen(1)
OSError: [WinError 10056] A connect request was made on an already connected socket
```

Scenario 2: 1. bind 2. listen 3. connect
Result: You can not connect or send at a listening socket.

```
>>> s = socket.socket()
>>> s.bind(('', 0))
>>> s.listen(1)
>>> s.connect(('google.de', 80))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#136>", line 1, in <module>
    s.connect(('google.de', 80))
OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied
>>> s.send(b"123")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#137>", line 1, in <module>
    s.send(b"123")
OSError: [WinError 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
```

Comment: Ah right, so, `bind()` is not only meant for listening for incoming connections (act as a server) but also to connect to a server (act as a client), correct? That actually makes sense, of course. So, concluding, we can't write to listening or unconnected sockets. I'm not sure I completely understand the question you pose in the end, though. Is it pertaining to the fact that when acting as a server you'll get a new socket per client, in stead of reading/writing to the already existing listening socket? And was it meant as a rhetorical question, perhaps?

Comment: I deleted the question.. I do not remember why i posted it. `bind` is used to assign a port to a socket. You need a port if you want to listen. You can specify a port for the socket before you connect from a specific port to a specific port, which makes no sense in many cases for TCP but may make sense for UDP sockets.